# document.getElementById.style.backgroundImage not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to assign different background images to a div depending on the page's address, so for example, if my url is http://www.mywebsite.com/mysubdirectory/ I use the following code:

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("mysubdirectory") >= 0){ 
   document.getElementById("wrapper").style.backgroundImage = "url('bg-wrapper.jpg')";
}
```

But it's not working. I even added a bogus document.write command just to make sure the rest of the code was ok and sure enough the bogus line showed up in my browser. Is there something I'm overlooking?

EDIT: Thank you all for your answers - when I use body instead of getElementById("wrapper") in my code, the image shows up, so I doubt it's a path-related issue. I trued adding an onload attribute to the body tag but it's still not working with getElementById. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the image in the root of your site?

Comment: Are you sure `bg-wrapper.jpg` is in the correct place... you probably need a relative path to it

Comment: Use firebug to see if it is loading the image or open up the image in IE using  http://www.mywebsite.com/mysubdirectory/bg-wrapper.jpg. More than likely it isn't loading. Second check for any script errors in firefox or ie debugger. Are you certain you have an element with the ID of wrapper? Did it accidentally get set as a class instead or spelling issues?

Comment: I think that problem is in the path of the image verification.

Comment: Sometimes images dont show up. Edit the image with paint or something else and save it as new `jpg`. It should work.

Comment: scrappedcola - the image was indeed not loading. Not sure how to get it to load though...?

Answer (score 8):

Your

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.backgroundImage = "url('bg-wrapper.jpg')";
```

code is correct.

It works fine in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hUuN5/

Are you sure the image is correct. Remember that the path to the file is relative to the location of the current page. NOT the css directory

Comment: Thank you, the relative path was the problem

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Chrome 29.0.1547.66 and none of the anwers worked either.

So I tried:

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.backgroundImage = "url(http://media.nu.nl/m/m1fz6dwa6h3w.jpg)";
```

It worked taking off the quotation marks from the image url.

Here working as well: http://jsfiddle.net/xEujg/

[html](/questions/tagged/html) [css](/questions/tagged/css) [backgroundimage](/questions/tagged/backgroundimage) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think the image url is wrong most likely. You probably need a relative path of sorts:

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.backgroundImage = "url('/bg-wrapper.jpg')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a protocol worked for me in chrome. I couldn't get it to work using the catch all '//'. It had to be 'http://' I'm assuming it must match whatever protocol was used to load the page or iframe.

for example
element.style.backgroundImage="url(http://somedomain.com/images/myimage.jpg)"
or 
element.style.backgroundImage="url('http://somedomain.com/images/myimage.jpg')"
worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var pointer =  "url(\'/" + imageArray[imageCounter].toString() + "\')";
document.body.style.backgroundImage = pointer
```

After spending a bit of time on this, it was the browser's engine parsing the CSS.  No good errors in the console.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still interested in this. Here is a solution:

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.background = "url(http://media.nu.nl/m/m1fz6dwa6h3w.jpg)";
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not do everything on the same line.

You have to create a variable, assign it the url and then pass it.

```
let bg = "url('" + imgUrl + "')";
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.backgroundImage = bg;
```