# How to change a background that is declared in .css not html

Tags: javascript, html, css

**USING JAVASCRIPT, NO JQUERY**
Hi all,
I know this is a basic one but I am hitting a dead end.
I want to change a background image that is in the `.css`, not the `html` so I cant give it an `id`. I managed to remove the image using:

```
var headerImg = document.getElementById('header').background = 'none';
```

And tried :

```
 var headerImg = document.getElementById('header').background = 'images/new-header.jpg;
```

But that did'nt work.
I have no idea how to change the Image, and in the dev tools the url does not even change when I try to run my code  Any help would be great, Thanks.

Comment: Possible [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320329/document-getelementbyid-style-backgroundimage-not-working)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.  You're just off on the syntax slightly...

```
document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url(images/new-header.jpg)";
```

It's a style attribute you're changing, so you need `.style` and then you use the CSS attribute name, but remove hyphens and camelCase the attribute name, so `.backgroundImage`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```js
var element = document.getElementById('content');
element.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSzOpUTzDIq2yutn75PQTLcHhJ06MTZPsV_V-0M918xKUhAqMxE')";
```

```html
<div>
  <p>this is unchanged</p>
  <p id="content">backgroud wiil be cange</p>
<div>
```